# PDFbox, preview List<PDPage> elements

Tags: java, pdf, pdfbox, preview

With the follow code I open a PDF file (with filechooser object, I don't show all the code here, it's not important) and then I "put" everything in a List od PDPage, where there are all the  PDF pages . If the PDF has 3 pages I will have 3 images , if the PDF has 4 pages I will have 4 images , etc ..

```
PDDocument document2 = PDDocument.loadNonSeq(new File(pdfFile), null);

            List<PDPage> pdPages = document2.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages();
```

In order to convert in BufferedImage I do this:

```
for (PDPage pdPage : pdPages)
            { 
                ++page;
                BufferedImage bim = pdPage.convertToImage(BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB, 300);
                ImageIOUtil.writeImage(bim, pdfFile + "-" + page + ".png", 300);
            }
```

and then I show, for example, one page in a stackpane. Now the problem, I want to show a preview of pdPages(so, no image format but PDPage) because I think is much better for big PDF. I mean, if I want to "convert" a PDF with 200 pages, it will take long time to complete the task. I thought to show a preview (maximum 10 or 15, it's not important) of the pages(in this way the user will click the interested image) but in PDPage format, not yet Image converted. I am thinking in the right way or I am wrong? In positive case, what can I do ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't have to save the image, you can keep these in an array of BufferedImage. To speed up things (for thumbnails), use a smaller dpi value, i.e. not 300 but maybe 50 or even less (try out what is best for you).

Comment: @TilmanHausherr Ok , but I would like keep all the elements as PDPage , then show them with a thumbnail in a Pane for example, and then when the user will want, click one of the elements and open in a new Jframe for example. At the moment the my topic is. How can I show PDPage elements with a thumbnail? Anyway, thanks for your tip about dpi.

Comment: A thumbnail is an image. Size doesn't matter. The only possibility is to render the PDPage object to a BufferedImage is with convertToImage(). PDPage is just a bunch of very complex data which won't display by itself.

Comment: So, Do I have to convert PDPage in am array of BufferedImage, right? IN your opionion is better to use a for loop or what other construct ? I ask this in order to manage very large PDF , for example, 300 or 400 pages . Of course, I will show only a few ( for example 10 ) previews a time. Thanks You are clarifying me my ideas

Comment: Yes, a loop is fine. Note that PDFBox is not thread safe, so don't do several conversions on the same document at the same time. So a solution might be to open the file twice, one to render the thumbnails in the background, the other to render a page in screen size.

Comment: PDFBox 2.0 has some experimental thread safety for read-only operations